# same name does not repeated again in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have table that looks like this:

```
employee table
================
number_new      -         number_old
123456(POC)                  123456(POC)
654656(GSON)                 9576767(VID)
55555                        55555
546464(XML)                  545454
```

---

I want output like this:

```
123456(POC)
654656(GSON)-9576767(VID)
55555 
546464(XML)-545454
```

Comment: Please reformat your question and make sure it is understandable to others. I have no idea what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CASE....

```
  SELECT 
     CASE WHEN NUMBER_NEW=NUMBER_OLD THEN NUMBER_NEW 
     ELSE NUMBER_NEW+'-'+NUMBER_OLD END AS 'SOMECOLUMN'
    FROM 
    YOURTABLE
```

**Output:**

```
123456(POC)
654656(GSON)-9576767(VID)
55555 
546464(XML)-545454
```